# Creating Facebook instance (Facebook App)

Tags: facebook

I've the following code in my iframe Facebook app

```
<?php
/* include the PHP Facebook Client Library to help
  with the API calls and make life easy */

require_once 'facebook.php';

$appapikey = 'key here';
$appsecret = 'secret here';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);



$facebook->require_frame();
$user_id = $facebook->require_login(); 

?>
```

The problem is that the app keeps loading and reloading.

Is my implementation wrong?

Comment: OK I got it.. Not exactly sure how it got fixed but this is what I did (In case someone is facing the same trouble!!)

1) Got to Privacy settings and remove the application and re authorize it!!

Comment: Are you using the old PHP-SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any check there. Everytime its just doing login. You have to check that user is logged or not if user is not logged then you have to run this code else do the action. I guess you must be having fb php sdk,check its demo example. If you dont got it download from [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/).